# Angular, function return true but ng-show won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

showOrHide function will return true if I click a link.

I tested this code with alert and console.log functions and it's work but if I want to test this code into ng-show or ng-hide directives it won't work. I can't understand this issue.

Sum: function return false, if I click some link it return true
But true and false won't work in ng-show.

angular.js file

```js
$scope.showOrHide = function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined')
        {
            return alert(true);
            //console.log("true");
            //return true;
        }else {
            return alert(false);
            //console.log("false");
            //return false;
        }
    };
    $scope.projectId = $stateParams.projectId;
    $scope.showOrHide($stateParams.projectId);
```

html file

```html
<tr ng-repeat="n in data.projects track by $index"
    ng-href="@{{n.id}}"
    ui-sref="goTo({ projectId: n.id })">
    <td>@{{n.project_code}}</td>
    <td>@{{n.project_name}}</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">@{{n.status}}</td>
    <td ng-show="showOrHide">test</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give up all of solutions because these are not working so I didn't revise my code. I changed all of them.

Here is the solution.

*JS File*

```
$scope.checkThis = true;

$scope.isShow = function (number) {
    return number;
};
$scope.toFalse = function () {
    $scope.checkThis = false;
};
$scope.toTrue = function () {
    $scope.checkThis = true;
};
```

*HTML File*

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in data.projects track by $index"
    ng-href="@{{n.id}}"
    ui-sref="goTo({ projectId: n.id })">
    <td>@{{n.project_code}}</td>
    <td>@{{n.project_name}}</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">@{{n.status}}</td>
    <td class="text-primary" ng-click="toFalse()"
                        ng-show="isShow(checkThis)">test</td>
                    </tr>
```

It's simple way, i think. I waste 3 hour the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You `ng-show` is based on a function not a variable so you need to write it as a function.

HTML:

```
<td ng-show="showOrHide('undefined')">test</td>
```

JS:

```
$scope.showOrHide = function (value) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined')
            return true;
        else 
            return false;

    };
```

Comment: It didn't show any data but I click one link for change return value but it didn't change. I don't understand this why is this happen

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you're trying to achieve (show the element only if a $stateParams.projectId exists) you can just use the variable you already set, so **remove the function** and just use the following:

cotroller:

```
app.controller('myController', function( $scope, $stateParams) {

  // other code here...

  $scope.projectId = $stateParams.projectId || false;
});
```

view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="n in data.projects track by $index"
    ng-href="@{{n.id}}"
    ui-sref="goTo({ projectId: n.id })">
    <td>@{{n.project_code}}</td>
    <td>@{{n.project_name}}</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">will add</td>
    <td class="text-primary">@{{n.status}}</td>
    <td ng-show="projectId">test</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create result variable like:

```
$scope.toShowOrToHide = $scope.showOrHide($stateParams.projectId);
```

ANd HTML:

```
<td ng-show="toShowOrToHide">test</td>
```

And JS return without alert:

```
$scope.showOrHide = function (value) {
    return (typeof value !== 'undefined');
};
```

Edited:

```
$scope.toShowOrToHide = function() {
    return $scope.showOrHide($stateParams.projectId);
);
```

And HTML:

```
<td ng-show="toShowOrToHide()">test</td>
```

You are probably decided what fits bes for you....

Comment: This is not good.  You want the ng-show to be checked in each digest (or you shouldn't be using ng-show) This example will not not show the element when the $stateParams.projectId changes.

Answer (score 0):

First

```
$scope.stateParams = $stateParams;
```

Then

```
ng-show="stateParams.projectId"
```

No function needed and value updates automatically when the param changes.